# Create a block device made of files

Tags: linux, block-device, device-mapper

#### TL;DR:

Given 2TB worth of 4MB files, how would I create a block device with those files as backing storage?

#### Background

I want to trial use of [Sia](http://sia.tech/) for storage, since:

> Storing 1TB on Sia costs about $2 per month, compared with $23 on Amazon S3.

The cost is so low since people are sharing their otherwise unused disk space.

[Regarding redundancy](https://blog.sia.tech/how-to-put-data-on-the-sia-network-784499a65b):

> Files are uploaded at 3x redundancy to 30 hosts. What this means is that 30 hosts end up with fragments of your data, and out of those hosts any 10 are enough to recover the original data.

Sia only provides storage for files, but I would like to use it to create a block device for versatility.

#### Non-options

Sia [operates on 4MB "sectors"](https://github.com/NebulousLabs/Sia/issues/1921#issuecomment-307914176), so creating a loopback device for each file would be silly.

I'd love to use [Ceph](http://www.ceph.com), but given [ext4 is not recommended](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/jewel/rados/configuration/filesystem-recommendations/#not-recommended) as a filesystem, I doubt that Sia's FUSE filesystem will cut the mustard. Either way, given [bluestore (block backed) eliminates double writes](http://ceph.com/community/new-luminous-bluestore/), using filestore would be super slow.